# Making global static variables multithread safe

Tags: c, multithreading, static-variables

I have global static variables in a C library, which generate exceptions in a multithread run. I need to make them safe in some way (i.e., each thread should relate to a different instance of these variables). Any recommended methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no standard way that works across all C implementations, but implementation-specific solutions exist.  For example, with Microsoft's compiler (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ax54352(VS.71).aspx)),

```
__declspec( thread ) int tls_i = 1;
```

makes `tls_i` live in thread-local storage (each thread has its own separate instance of this variable).  With [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html#Thread_002dLocal), the syntax is

```
__thread int tls_i;
```

You may also want to check the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) on the subject.

Comment: @giladsah: Read the second half of the answer!

Comment: @giladsah, sure, the `__thread` keyword as I just said in my answer (I also pointed to a `gcc` doc page about thread-local storage for more details).

Answer (score 4):

First question:

- do the threads need their own copies of the variables?
- or do they need to coordinate access to a single shared copy?

If you need the former, the other answers have made suggestions about 'thread-local storage'.

If you need the latter, then somehow or another you need to ensure there's an appropriate mutex on those variables (the scope of the mutex is one of the issues you face), and that the threads all use the mutex, and release the mutex.  This is trickier.  It may even be that you need to provide functions that control access to the variables.

The standard variable `errno` can be a modifiable lvalue:

```
extern int *_errno_func(void);
#define errno (*(_errno_func)())
```

In a threaded application (compiled with -DREENTRANT), this is what happens; on MacOS X, it appears to be what happens anyway (they use the name `__error` instead of `_errno_func`; both are in the implementation's namespace).

You may want to, or end up having to, do something similar for your variables.  The fact that you say they are static improves things a bit.  You only have one file to deal with (unless you are careless enough to pass back - or on - pointers to those variables).

Answer (score 3):

What you needed is **TLS(Thread Local Storage)**, which is also known as **thread-specific data** or **thread-private data**. This mechanism can guarantee each thread to access its own separate copy of data, without worrying about synchronizing access with other threads.

---

There are two methods to use TLS:

1. **implicit: using keyword**

   **Windows:** __declspec(thread) int tls_var = 10;

   **Linux with GCC:** __thread int tls_var = 10
2. **explicit: using specific TLS related API**

   **Windows:**

     **TlsAlloc():**
     allocate memory for tls data

     **TlsFree():**
     free the memory of tls data

     **TlsSetValue():**
     set tls' value

     **TlsGetValue():**
     get tls' value

   Please refer to MSDN for detailed information.

   **LInux with GCC:**

     **pthread_key_create()**
     : create the tls data

     **pthread_key_delete()**
     : destory the tls data

     **pthread_getspecific()**
     : get tls' value

     **pthread_setspecific**
     (): set tls' value

   Turn to manpage for specific and detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers have some way of designating thread-local storage. Assuming it's available, that's what you want.